# Where can I find the PRINCE2 study material?

Tags: prince2

I just passed the PMP 2 months ago, and I would like to start PRINCE2 foundation and practitioner exam as soon as possible.

I self-studied the PMP too and am looking for good study material.

I have search on this Q&A site, and I found the following recommendation. 
1. Official Prince2 Manual (equivalent to PMP PMBOK)
2. PRINCE2 For Dummies
3. PRINCE2 Study Guide by David Hinde

Do I need study all three books above? Or do I just need to study one of them?
Where can I find the official PRINCE2 manual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your most cost-effective approach is probably to go to any of a number of online education providers. They will provide you with the manual (~$100) and should also cover the costs of the examinations (IIRC ~$400 each) as well as practice questions, webinars, etc etc.

If you want to go it alone the title for the Prince2 manual is "Managing Successful Projects with PRINCE2", it is widely available through online book sellers. It is fairly well written (far better than PMBOK) so I didn't have a need to go with other books.

Answer (score 0):

A PRINCE2 Foundation Exam Trainer demo account can be asked for here: http://elearning.pm4all.be/Apps/En/Home/About/ContactUs.aspx?Category=3&Type=3&From=Blog. You can use the dropdown list to select what you want: a 1 month demo account with 25 questions or a 1 day demo with all questions available. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a already a big advantage as you are a PMP. You can then just first focus on learning the PRINCE2 process.

PRINCE2 Foundation:
- As a PMP, you do not need to do this exam
- You are entitled to sit the PRINCE2 Practitioner Exam directly

PRINCE2 Practitioner
- You will need the official book: Managing Successful Projects...
- Most people do a classroom training
- But a Self Study is a lot more cost effective: Ggoogle "PRINCE2 Online Course"

**Tips for getting into the PRINCE2 Process:**

1) The PRINCE2 Timeline video (20 mins) 
   - http://bit.do/P2-Timeline
   - This is a simple high-level introduction to a PRINCE2 Project

2) PRINCE2 Pre-Course - (60 mins video)
- Search on Youtube for this video  "PRINCE2 Pre-Course"
- It shows you how a PRINCE2 project works

Useful site: 1) SlideShare, 2) PRINCE2.wiki 3) AXELOS.com